# Ensuring the order of columns returned in jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Maps for a given query using JDBCTemplate. The following method seems to be apt for my use case:

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> queryForList(String sql)
                                      throws DataAccessException
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-

However, I want to make sure that for a given row, the Map's order is guaranteed. i.e, A LinkedHashMap would be better as I want to preserve the order of columns. Is there a better way to achieve this using JDBCTemplate?

Answer (score 5):

I think it'll work to use a custom ColumnMapRowMapper that creates a LinkedHashMap for each row, then pass this to the query method:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-

```
    RowMapper<Map<String, Object>> rowMapper = new ColumnMapRowMapper()
    {
        protected Map<String, Object> createColumnMap(int columnCount) 
        {
            return new LinkedHashMap<>(columnCount);
        }
    };

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

    String sql = "SELECT ...";      

    try
    {           
        List<Map<String,Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
        // ...
    }
    catch(DataAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact I just found while doing this myself... if you use a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, which is better anyway, the column ordering will be ensured by default.

For example, the queryForList() method ends up creating a ColumnMapRowMapper():

```
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource)
        throws DataAccessException {

    return query(sql, paramSource, new ColumnMapRowMapper());
}
```

Which uses this in its implementation:

```
    /**
     * Create a Map instance to be used as column map.
     * <p>By default, a linked case-insensitive Map will be created.
     * @param columnCount the column count, to be used as initial
     * capacity for the Map
     * @return the new Map instance
     * @see org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap
     */
    protected Map<String, Object> createColumnMap(int columnCount) {
        return new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<>(columnCount);
    }
```

The linked hash map will preserve ordering appropriately.